# How to programmatically update commerce data templates

Tags: sitecore-commerce

I am using Sitecore XC 9.1 and want to programmatically trigger a update of the Commerce data templates. This will, for example, be handy in my CI setup.

How to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `CatalogTemplateGenerator` class to perform the desired actions, e.g. to delete and build:

```
var master = Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetDatabase("master");
var generator = new Sitecore.Commerce.Engine.Connect.DataProvider.Templates.CatalogTemplateGenerator();

generator.DeleteAllGeneratedTemplates(master);
generator.BuildCatalogTemplates(master);
```

NB. the GUI triggers this code by `Sitecore.Commerce.Engine.Connect.DataProvider.Commands.GenerateTemplatesCommand`.